# Is the Roland TD-17 a drop-in replacement for TD-12?

Tags: electronic-drumset

A few years ago, I sold my TD-12 drum module to pay the bills.  Since then, my V-Drums have been sat in the box screaming out to be played and I think I'm just about in a position to replace the module with a new one.

I'm looking at the newer modules offered (specifically the TD-17 module) and it appears the inputs have changed a little.  The modules only seem to have 2 inputs and the rest of the inputs come in elsewhere.  Can I keep my old stand and just upgrade the module, or do I need to buy a new stand too?

If anyone has any of the newer modules and can give more detailed pictures of the bottom, that would be amazing.

Comment: Roland is a very helpful company. Drop them an e-mail.

Comment: Before you VTC, please read the question carefully. It is **not** a product recommendation question in any way at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TD-17 is different from the TD-12 in several ways, but there are two ways it is different that are important for you.

First, the trigger connections are different. On the TD-12, there is a separate 1/4" trigger input for each trigger channel. On the TD-17, there is a [single "multicore" cable](https://www.drum-tec.com/Multicore-Cable-for-Roland-TD-9/TD-11/TD-15/TD-25) (I believe the connector is a DB-25) that breaks out into trigger cables. You'll have to buy one of these and use it to connect your triggers.

Second, the stand mount is very different. The TD-12 mount is a bracket that screws on to the bottom of the module and presents a tube mount, while the TD-17 has a dedicated slide-in mounting system. While I was able to find the multicore trigger cable separately, I wasn't able to find a separate TD-17 stand. I think asking Roland, as Tim suggested, may be a good way to go, or paying a visit or making a phone call to your favorite retailer.

My resources for this were:

[English TD-17 owner's manual (PDF download)](https://static.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/TD-17_eng01_W.pdf)

[English TD-12 owner's manual (PDF download)](https://static.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/TD-12_OM.pdf)

Note that there are graphics showing the bottom of the TD-17 and the stand mount in the manual linked above.

Comment: Thank you, I'll get in touch with Roland and add my own answer if I get a response.